# My SQL query will not output the field result correctly

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to run a query which will provide a user on the website with:

- The competition name
- The image title
- The result (1st place, 2nd place or 3rd)

So far I have managed to pull out the below result:

[image: Screenshot of web page]

```
<div class="grid-2">
    <h3>Competition Entries</h3>
        <form action = "" method = "POST">
        <select name="competitionID">
        <option value="">Select Competition</option>
        <option value="1">Winter Warmer</option>
        <option value="2">Fresh New Year</option>
        <option value="3">Month of Love</option>
        <option value="4">Seaside Scenery</option>
        </select>
        </fieldset>
     </form>
<?php

    $query = "SELECT `fldCompName`, `fldName`, `fldResult` FROM `tblMembEntComp` JOIN `tblCompetition` ON `tblMembEntComp`.`fldCompID`=`tblCompetition`.`fldCompID` JOIN `tblImage` ON `tblMembEntComp`.`fldMemberID`=`tblImage`.`fldMemberID` ORDER BY `fldResult` DESC LIMIT 3";

$result = $conn -> query($query);

while($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) 
    {
        echo $row['fldCompName']." ".$row['fldName']." ".$row['fldResult']."<br>";
    } 
    ?>
    <button>View Competition Winners</button>
</div>
```

However, the results are all showing up as 17 for all of those top three entries when in the `tbmMembEntComp` `fldResult` I have 19, 17 and 11. Can someone just highlight where I've gone wrong and give guidance on what the query should be.
[image: table in phpMyAdmin]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not limiting the results  to one specific competition, therefore it gives *all* the joined rows between member table and competition table.

Something like this (example only)

```sql
SELECT `fldCompName`, `fldName`, `fldResult`  
FROM `tblMembEntComp`  
JOIN `tblCompetition` ON `tblMembEntComp`.`fldCompID`=`tblCompetition`.`fldCompID`
-- EXAMPLE
AND `tblCompetition`.`fldCompID` = {someX}
------ 
JOIN `tblImage` ON tblMembEntComp`.`fldMemberID`=`tblImage`.`fldMemberID` 
ORDER BY `fldResult` DESC LIMIT 3";
```

Comment: Hi @DinoCoderSaurus, do you know where in the query I should just state which competition please?

Comment: Modifying the sql is simple: in the ON clause of the tblCompetion join use something like `and compID = someX`. If your intention is that `someX` is  based on user selection in the drop down, you would need instead an ajax call (to the server). The php runs one time when the page loads, and not again.

Comment: I've just given it a try pasting it in that ON clause for tblComp and it doesn't seem to like where I pasted it, after which part of the code do you mean (sorry to ask specifics) :)

Comment: added an example to the answer.

Comment: Technically a cartesian join returns all possibilities between two tables (i.e., all members paired with all competitions) but a `JOIN` is used between tables. A `JOIN` without `ON` (or `CROSS JOIN`) would be a cartesian join. OP is just not filtering to selected competition in form. Here, *{somex}* should be [parameterized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: Corrected the language in the answer to avoid further confusion.

Comment: Thank you, It's still coming up with 17 as the 3 results even with the compID set as 2 for e.g, as apposed to 19, 17 and 11. It must be the join I have done, I'll have a look into this again tonight

Comment: Assume you are testing the SELECT in phyMyAdmin before abstracting it to the php. Maybe a `WHERE` would be better than the change to the `JOIN`. Good luck!